# count arguments in shell script running in java

Tags: java, spring-boot, shell

I've saved some shell scripts within my java projects. Im getting all of them with following method:

```
public List<String> getResourceFiles() throws IOException {
    String path = "shellScripts";
    List<String> filenames = new ArrayList<>();
    try (
            InputStream in = getResourceAsStream(path);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in))) {
        String resource;

        while ((resource = br.readLine()) != null) {
            filenames.add(resource);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(filenames);
    return filenames;
}

private InputStream getResourceAsStream(String resource) {
    final InputStream in
            = getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(resource);

    return in == null ? getClass().getResourceAsStream(resource) : in;
}
```

If i chose one of the script I want to return the number of existing arguments in the shell script. Here is an example: passingTwoArguments.sh

passingTwoArguments.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'First arg:' $1
echo 'Second arg:' $2
```

In this example it should return 2. Do u know some best practices? Im not sure if i could define the name and arguments within some metadata tables, which i dont know what it is

Comment: You'd need to parse the shell script and extract parameter references. I'm not an expert here but if you _know_ the parameters are always referenced by `$n` then all you'd need to do is extract that pattern and parse it to get the highest value of `n`. As far as I know even if a script would just use `$5` you'd need to pass 5 arguments so you don't have to could the number of arguments, just get the highest number (unless you want to count the number of used vs. ignored arguments that is).

Comment: Im not quiet sure how to do it. Can u give me sone code hint?

Comment: I don't understand _why_ you want to do this. Shell scripts are not strict about variables: if a variable has not been set, attempting to use it is not an error (unless `set -u`) and the empty string is substituted. Also, just searching a file for a regex pattern (such as `\$\{?(\d+)(\W|$)`) is insufficient because shell functions also use the positional parameter syntax, and you can easily have a function that takes more arguments than the actual script does.

Comment: Don't do this. That way lies madness.

Comment: I kinda need to. I've got a frontend in which i can select the shell script. The chosen script then should be ran. Some of the scripts have arguments which need to be filled, e.g. calculator,...
For that i have to "scan" the script and return the number of arguments.
Could i declare the number of arguments as metadata? As i said i dont know much about metadata. Until now i have never used it

Comment: You might want to use some form of metadata then. If your script just uses `$1` etc. how would you match that to a more meaningful name? You'd probably not be able to extract the meaning of each parameter without any kind of metadata - so keep it somewhere.

Comment: Could u give me a hint about that metadata? Do you know some examples? Im not sure in which language the metadata has to be written in